# Can anyone tell me why the following Python code is generating None in the output?

Tags: python

```
def hourstominutes(minutes):

    hours = minutes/60
    return hours


h = int(input(print("Enter the number of minutes:")))

print(hourstominutes(h))
```

Comment: Why are you calling `print()` inside `input()`? The argument to `input()` is a string to print as the prompt.

Comment: What is the output that you're getting?

Comment: `input` takes a string and prints it to the screen then waits for input. `print` prints to the screen and doesn't return anything, that is, it returns `None`, which then `input` prints. Yes, input does 2 things instead of 1.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar it's working fine now :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I understood the difference.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are adding the function `print()` within your input code, which is creating a `None` first, followed by the user input. Here is the solution:

```
def hours_to_minutes(minutes):
    hours = minutes/60
    return hours

h = int(input("Enter the number of minutes: "))
print(hours_to_minutes(h))
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of minutes: 50
0.8333333333333334
```

Answer (score 0):

Input is printing the result of `print("Enter the number of minutes:"`, and `print()` returns None.  What you want is `int(input("Enter the number of minutes:"))` with no `print()`.