# None appereance in a if statment

Tags: python-3.x

Why is "None" appearing me?

I made other code similar to that and "None" dindn't appear me.
What can I do to stop appear me the "None" sentence?

```
first_question = str(input(print("Who do you bet for? ")))

if first_question == "tim" or first_question == "tess" or first_question == "alex" or first_question == "duck" or first_question  == "dog":

    bet = int(input(print("How much you bet? ")))

    if bet < 0:
        print("The bet can't take negative valours! ")
        bet = int(input(print("How much you bet? ")))
        while bet < 0:
            print("The bet can't take negative valours! ")
            bet = int(input(print("How much you bet? ")))

    if bet > my_money:
        print("The bet can't be above the money you have! ")
        bet = int(input(print("How much you bet? ")))
        while bet > my_money:
            print("The bet can't be above the money you have! ")
            bet = int(input(print("How much you bet? ")))

    if bet >= 0 and bet <= my_money:
        total_money = my_money - bet
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can anyone tell me why the following Python code is generating None in the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087911/can-anyone-tell-me-why-the-following-python-code-is-generating-none-in-the-outpu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your syntax for the `input` is wrong. Here's the correct usage:

```
 a = input("Enter a value")
```

No need to use `print` inside `input`. Correct these, everything will be fine.

2. By default, input returns string values. So there is no need to explicitly type convert the input value to a string.

```
>>> a = input("Enter any value?...")
Enter any value?...10

>>> print(type(a))
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Thanks! I am still a beginner!

Answer (score 0):

If you use print as the argument to input, then print return a value that you've not defined. Print will succeed and by doing this return None. Every functions returns something, and in the case with print, it is None.

Remove print as a start?  `first_question = str(input(print("Who do you bet for? ")))`  -->  `first_question = input("Who do you bet for? ")`

Then you'd need to define my_money, and catch the case when the user enters something else than what's in your list, using an else-statement at the end.